# Jquery.form (3.51.0-2014.06.20) fileupload not working in IE9 (sharepoint application)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sharepoint-online

Ok, before I start let me say I did look at almost all answers in SO and elsewhere reg. jq form upload issues and confident that this issue is different.

What basically happens is the file upload goes fine and a response is returned in application/json format with a ID from the upload controller. Initially in IE the response was prompting for a download and to solve that I changed the content type to text/json (text/html,text/xml). Now it does not prompt for download anymore but  when I try to access the response looking for the return values it comes up empty. The code looks like this and xhr.responseText is empty.

```
 $('#upload-file-data-form').ajaxSubmit({
                    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
                    url: url,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { DataItems : "some data" },
                    complete: function (xhr) {
                        var json = xhr.responseText;
                        var data = $.parseJSON(json);
                        onDone(data.d);
                    },
                    errors: function () {
                        onFail();
                    }
                });
```

Fiddler extract of the returned JSON.

[image]

The application is hosted in SP online and the the upload happens to a web api endpoint in azure. Since this works fine in chrome and IE11 I'm assuming this is a CORS issue in IE9. I have been messing with this more than 2 days now and I'd buy a beer (no joke! :) ) for anyone who can shed some light on this.

Cheers!

Comment: I believe IE9 has to preflight a CORS request; have you read this article yet? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/02/09/cors-for-xhr-in-ie10.aspx

Comment: Yes I saw that. The thing in this situation is, it does the POST (upload) fine. And the response comes through fine too with a 200. But the ResponseText is getting lost somewhere in the jqeury libraries I can't figure where.

Answer (score 0):

It might be, because you have a Syntax-Error in your Code:

```
data: { "some data" }
```

Choose between (submit an Object)

```
data: { name: "firstname"}
```

or an Array

```
data: ["some data"]
```

Comment: I think he did that to save space, hence `"some data"`.

Comment: no that's not the case I'm afraid. I just edited that to remove the clutter. The post happens fine and file is getting uploaded and its' only the response from the server getting lost.